React Native Expo with Drizzle ORM and Convex: Cannot use import statement outside a module
I am using Expo Sqlite with Drizzle ORM:
My drizzle.config.ts:
import  { Config } from "drizzle-kit"

export default {
  schema: "./lib/db/schema",
  out: "./lib/db/migrations",
  dialect: "sqlite",
  driver: "expo",
} satisfies Config

When I try and run npx drizzle-kit generate I get the following error:
No config path provided, using default 'drizzle.config.ts'
Reading config file '/Users/jay/Documents/personal/Code/Expo/pretty-budgeter/drizzle.config.ts'
/Users/jay/Documents/personal/Code/Expo/pretty-budgeter/node_modules/react-native/index.js:14
import typeof ActionSheetIOS from './Libraries/ActionSheetIOS/ActionSheetIOS';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1281:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1321:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1416:10)
    at newLoader (/Users/jay/Documents/personal/Code/Expo/pretty-budgeter/node_modules/drizzle-kit/bin.cjs:14724:13)
    at Object.newLoader (/Users/jay/Documents/personal/Code/Expo/pretty-budgeter/node_modules/drizzle-kit/bin.cjs:14724:13)
    at extensions..js (/Users/jay/Documents/personal/Code/Expo/pretty-budgeter/node_modules/drizzle-kit/bin.cjs:17252:28)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1208:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1024:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1233:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:179:18

I've gone through the docs over and over again and have looked through issues on Expo's sqlite repo and drizzle's.
So far what I can tell is that:

I have set everything up correctly according to the docs.
Generating the migrations outside of this project and then adding them to the project works.


Update:
This is now also happening with Convex db, whenever I try and run npx convex dev the same thing happens as above. This didn't happen initially though, at first the command ran fine and at some point those errors started happening.

Add these recently, conclusion was that the path of my schema was invalid

Try to add "type": "module" to your package.json or rename the file to drizzle.config.mts.

Unfortunately none of those worked

Try replacing "import typeof ActionSheetIOS from './Libraries/ActionSheetIOS/ActionSheetIOS';"
with "import type ActionSheetIOS from './Libraries/ActionSheetIOS/ActionSheetIOS';"

It's in node_modules, I can't change that everytime and there are also many of those in that file, that's just the first line.

Check your schema, I found the same issue then I remove an imported generateId function from other file and it works

Not that, I don't have anything like that in there.
